# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "Table"."Col" does not exist, when using double quotes

Tags: java, postgresql

I'm writing a Java application to automatically build and run SQL queries using Postgres. Many queries work fine, however when I use double quotes in table and column names it throw an exception. Here one example:

```
SELECT "exploration_Table"."wlbNCS" as wea_wlbNCS,"well_Top"."lsuStrat" as wea_lsuStrat FROM "exploration_Table", well_Top WHERE "well_Top"."lsuStrat"="exploration_Table"."wlbFormationID"
```

I need the double quotes to preserve the capitalisation of tables and columns names, but it shows this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column exploration_Table.wlbNCS does not exist
```

The table and column name are exist in the database and they are correct, How could I avoid this error?

Comment: Then the column `exploration_Table.wlbNCS`  is not capitalized that way. Use `psql` to connect to the database and see how the table and column names are actually capitalized. I'm guessing they where not double quoted when defined and are actually lower case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out the exact way the tables are in the database, in terms of lower/upper case, then apply that to your query.

Also you should consider using back ticks instead of double quotes to preserve column names.